# Alfresco Process Services with TaskListener @Autowired issue

Tags: spring-boot, activiti

I am using Alfresco Process Services and have created a created a spring boot project for custom logic like **TaskListeners** and **Delegations**. I am creating the **jar** file from this maven project and copying it into **webapps/activiti-app/WEB-INF/lib** folder.

I have a simple **TaskListener** as below which is getting called on Task start. But the **@Autowired** variables are always **null**.

```
package com.activiti.extension.bean;

@Component("myTaskListener")
public class MyTaskListener implements TaskListener {

@Autowired
UserService userService;

@Override
public void notify(DelegateTask task) { 
   logger.info("userService: " +userService); // Always prints null
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I was able to make it work. I was putting the task listener in the class field of the Task properties with full package name. Now I am putting Delegate expression like ${myTaskListener} and it worked...

Thank you all for your time and help

Answer (score 1):

This is because your your `MyTaskListener` is annotated as [@Component](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-stereotype-annotations) or at least being ignored by spring during init. for auto-wiring capabilities spring requires this annotation (or similar to this) under the provided @ComponentScan packages to consider the class as a bean otherwise it will take as a normal java class and hence the `@autowired` is of no use in your case.

Comment: I tried removing and adding the @Component but it is not working. I put a logger in the constructor of the MyTaskListener class and when I start the server APS it is getting printed... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This below code is worked for me

```
@Component
 public class MyTaskListener implements TaskListener {
    public static UserService getUserServiceObject() {
    return SpringApplicationContextHolder.getApplicationContext().getBean(UserService.class);
  }
@Override
  public void notify(DelegateTask delegateTask) {
  //UserService Object, It is not null now
   getUserServiceObject(); 
  }
}

@Component
public class SpringApplicationContextHolder implements ApplicationContextAware {

private static ApplicationContext applicationContext = null;

public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
    return applicationContext;
}

@Override
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
   this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also one more way to get to your custom service "UserService" using **Alfresco Spring Application context**.

First access ServiceRegistry (registry used for accessing Alfresco    Services but also any other custom service):

```
ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = (ServiceRegistry) Context.getProcessEngineConfiguration().getBeans().get(ActivitiConstants.SERVICE_REGISTRY_BEAN_KEY);
```

Then get custom service UserService:

```
QName qname = QName.createQName("UserService");
UserService userService = (UserService) serviceRegistry.getService(qname);
```